# why can't I get my password to generate on the site for my password generator?

Tags: javascript, html, css, passwords

I am trying to make a password generator with prompts and everything seems to be working but I cannot seem to get my generated password to appear on the site. Here is what I have so far:

```
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");

var specialCharacters = [
  "!",
  "@",
  "#",
  "$",
  "%",
  "^",
  "&",
  "*",
  "(",
  ")",
  "_",
  "-",
  "+",
  "?",
  "/",
  "<",
  ">"
];
var upperCase = [
  "A",
  "B",
  "C",
  "D",
  "E",
  "F",
  "G",
  "H",
  "I",
  "J",
  "K",
  "L",
  "M",
  "N",
  "O",
  "P",
  "Q",
  "R",
  "S",
  "T",
  "U",
  "V",
  "W",
  "X",
  "Y",
  "Z"
];
var lowerCase = [
  "a",
  "b",
  "c",
  "d",
  "e",
  "f",
  "g",
  "h",
  "i",
  "j",
  "k",
  "l",
  "m",
  "n",
  "o",
  "p",
  "q",
  "r",
  "s",
  "t",
  "u",
  "v",
  "w",
  "x",
  "y",
  "z"
];
var numeric = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];

generateBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var passLength = prompt(
    "How many characters would you like your password to contain?"
  );

  if (passLength < 8) {
    alert("Password length must be between 8 - 128 characters");
    passLength = prompt(
      "Please choose a number more than 8 and less than 128 characters: "
    );
  }

  if (passLength >= 8) {
    var charInput = confirm("Would you like to use special characters?");
    var numInput = confirm("Would you like to use numbers?");
    var lowerCaseInput = confirm("Would you like to use lowercase letters?");
    var upperCaseInput = confirm("Would you like to use uppercase letters?");
  }

  if (!charInput && !numInput && !lowerCaseInput && !upperCaseInput) {
    alert("You must select at least one character type!");
    charInput = confirm("Would you like to use special characters?");
    numInput = confirm("Would you like to use numbers?");
    lowerCaseInput = confirm("Would you like to use lowercase letters?");
    upperCaseInput = confirm("Would you like to use uppercase letters?");
  }

  var passOutput = {
    passLength,
    charOutput: charInput,
    numericOutput: numInput,
    lowerCaseOutput: lowerCaseInput,
    upperCaseOutput: upperCaseInput
  };

  console.log(passOutput);
  return passOutput;
});

function writePassword() {
  var password = generatePassword();
  console.log(password);

  var randomPassword = [];
  console.log(randomPassword);

  if (password.charOutput) {
    for (i = 0; i < specialCharacters.length; ++i) {
      randomPassword.push(specialCharacters[i]);
    }
  }
  if (password.numericOutput) {
    for (i = 0; i < numeric.length; ++i) {
      randomPassword.push(numeric[i]);
    }
  }
  if (password.lowerCaseOutput) {
    for (i = 0; i < lowerCase.length; ++i) {
      randomPassword.push(lowerCase[i]);
    }
  }
  if (password.upperCaseOutput) {
    for (i = 0; i < upperCase.length; ++i) {
      randomPassword.push(upperCase[i]);
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < password.length; ++i) {
    var randomPassword = Math.floor(
      Math.random() * Math.floor(randomPassword.length)
    );
    passwordText.push(randomPassword);
  }

  console.log(generatePassword);
  document.getElementById("password").value = generatePassword;
}
```

Comment: Plz include the `HTML` also.

Comment: Where does `generatePassword` come from? First you are calling it as if it is a function, then later you assign it to `.value` as if it is a string.

Comment: Looks like you're invoking a function generatePassword() and setting the value of password to the return. But I don't see anywhere you've declared and defined that function.

Comment: how would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your button event is not actually invoking your writePassword function. Also that function doesn't seem to have access to the values that the button event would return in either case. So I would suggest you either create a variable to hold the return value of the button event or you invoke the writePassword function from the button event.

```
  console.log(passOutput);
  writePassword(passOutput);
```

And then in your writePassword function, you call a function that does not exist and at the end you try to output it as well. For the example I've shown this should take a parameter which is an object that contains the users options. I don't know what type of field you're outputting the value in at the bottom since I don't know what your HTML looks like so you might need to change the .innerHTML to .value again if you're assigning that to a field.

```
function writePassword(password) {
  var randomPassword = [];
  console.log(randomPassword);

  if (password.charOutput) {
    for (i = 0; i < specialCharacters.length; ++i) {
      randomPassword.push(specialCharacters[i]);
    }
  }
  if (password.numericOutput) {
    for (i = 0; i < numeric.length; ++i) {
      randomPassword.push(numeric[i]);
    }
  }
  if (password.lowerCaseOutput) {
    for (i = 0; i < lowerCase.length; ++i) {
      randomPassword.push(lowerCase[i]);
    }
  }
  if (password.upperCaseOutput) {
    for (i = 0; i < upperCase.length; ++i) {
      randomPassword.push(upperCase[i]);
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < password.length; ++i) {
    var randomPassword = Math.floor(
      Math.random() * Math.floor(randomPassword.length)
    );
    passwordText.push(randomPassword);
  }

  console.log(randomPassword);
  document.getElementById("password").innerHTML = randomPassword;
}
```

You should note that this is not actually creating a random password, your loops are simply pushing the entire content of the arrays you've defined into the new array. And then in the last loop, you start using a new variable "passwordText" that isn't used anywhere else in your code. You might want to step through the logic of what you're doing a bit so you can refine this.

I'd suggest writing down what you need to happen at each step in the function then trying to write out the code for that particular step and confirm it is doing what you want it to do.

I'd also suggest that you not use prompts and confirmation boxes because that makes testing a pain to say the least, its also bad practice to use those as a lot of adBlockers tend to block them by default, especially if you have a lot of them. Create some input fields to take in the options from the user rather than using prompts.

Comment: i tried what you suggested and im still having trouble :heres my html

Comment: Your html looks similar to the html that I used to test this. If you made the changes I suggested then you should be getting an output on screen now. What trouble are you having.

Comment: my generated password still doesnt shwo after the last prompt

Comment: It works heres a JSFiddle to show you.

https://jsfiddle.net/9st70hmf/

Comment: I updated it to show that it does indeed your html as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/trontastic/8pL62doh/1/

Comment: thank you for all the help! i had a typo in one of my variables thats why it wasn't working